# Upgrade from 1.9.2.4 to 1.9.3.1 results in no results on search Collection.php issue

Tags: collection, search, magento1.9.3.1

I'm using the default `Collection.php` for search.

With the new `1.9.3.1` the search bar for typing the search shows the search terms so it is clear it has results but then the results page says **"Your search returns no results."**

I replaced the `/app/code/core/Mage/CatalogSearch/Model/Resource/Fulltext/Collection.php` file with the old 1.9.2.4 and now I get results.

Yes, this works but this is not a good solution.
Since others are not having this issue, what might be wrong with my configuration causing the new version to fail.

Did not include the code since it should be standard:

```
-rw-rw-rw- 1 bitnami bitnami 2791 Feb 24  2016 Collection.php
-rw-rw-rw- 1 bitnami bitnami 6789 Nov 30 15:29 Collection.php-new-2016-12-14
```

Notice the big difference in **file length** between the new version and the old. Assume some major changes and one of them must have a conflict with some other setting or maybe customization I'm not aware of.

Comment: Try to reindex. If using additional extension for search autocomplete, check if compatible with the new 1.9.3 changes. See this if using BetterStoreSearch extension: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/147842/search-issue-on-magento-1-9-3-1

Comment: Everything was reindexed, that did not do the trick. The search shows suggestions as I type so it sees the results but there is some issue when the Collection.php page generates the results. Not using any search extensions, vanilla Magento. Guessing some configuration issue via the UI effecting the new Collection.php update or some issue in a custom layout that interferes with the new code checks.